# mysql count latest record from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

```
patient
```

| id | name | room |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | A |
| 2 | Ben | B |
| 3 | Charles | A |
| 4 | David | C |
| 5 | Eugen | B |

and table `check`:

| id | id_patient | check_date | condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-11-11 | bad |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-11-12 | good |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-11-17 | good |
| 4 | 3 | 2021-11-17 | poor |
| 5 | 4 | 2021-11-18 | bad |
| 6 | 5 | 2021-11-18 | bad |
| 7 | 3 | 2021-12-20 | poor |
| 8 | 4 | 2021-12-20 | bad |
| 9 | 5 | 2021-12-21 | bad |
| 7 | 1 | 2021-12-22 | bad |
| 8 | 2 | 2021-12-22 | poor |
| 9 | 3 | 2021-12-23 | good |

how the query to count patient by room from latest condition  check date record .. Need result like this :

| room | bad | good | poor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Try to clarify the explanation for the result you want, it's pretty hard to understand what you're trying to say!

Comment: Need to count patient by room from latest check result record. I need the result like 3rd table

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
select room, 
       sum(case when result = "bad" then 1 else 0 end) as bad,
       sum(case when result = "good" then 1 else 0 end) as good,
       sum(case when result = "poor" then 1 else 0 end) as poor
from 
    (select c3.id, patient, room, checkdate, result 
     from checks c3
     inner join patients pt on pt.id = c3.patient
     where c3.id in
         (select id
          from checks c1
          where patient = c3.patient and 
                          (select max(checkdate) 
                           from checks c2  
                           where c2.patient = c1.patient) = checkdate)) ch

group by room
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/irBJY8JwxPygQZj7LYPofv/4